# I can't connect wireless network when wakeup after Sleep & Hibernate

Tags: wireless

When I put my pc to sleep or hibernate, after that when I open(wakeup) Ubuntu. My wireless connection cannot connect to internet.

So in this case I need to restart again... what is the solution?

Comment: Can you add some hardware information to your question?

Answer (score 6):

try [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1483854):

Here is a technique that works for many. Please open Applications > Accessories > Terminal and do:

Code:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

You will learn details about your wired and wireless card. For example, here is my wireless detail. You need the exact name of your wireless driver.

Quote:

```
*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
vendor: Intel Corporation
--- snip ---
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 ip=192.168.1.108
```

Next do:

Code:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

The text editor gedit will open. Type in:

Code:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwl3945"
```

Substitute the driver name you found. Proofread carefully, save and close gedit.

Suspend and report your success.

Comment: Did not work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

I have a sony vaio vpc and have experienced the same problem. One thing that seems to work consistently is turning of my wireless before I suspend. My laptop has a button for this, so I just have to flick the switch. When I come back from suspend, I turn the wireless back on once I have logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you simply need to restart your network manager.

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```